# Icon not going extreme right even after setting "to the right" of layout

Tags: android, layout

I am setting the "cross" icon to the right of "list" layout but it is not going extreme right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#666666" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mylist"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/wrong" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove to right of from ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

in `RelativeLayout` tag to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

toRightOf is a property for children of RelativeLayout. Your ImageView is not inside a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

User `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, I tried all of your code with just `RelativeLayout` as main parent layout and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#666666" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wrong" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```